# How to count how many and what kind of digits are found in a string and replace all letters with spaces?

Tags: c++, string, char

I need to solve this task using library string functions and without them.

I solved without special functions:

```
void without_functions(string str)
{
    int* how_many_num = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        how_many_num[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        {
            ++how_many_num[int(str[i]) - 48];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        if (how_many_num[i] != 0)
        {
            cout << "Digit " << i << " is founded" << how_many_num[i] << " times" << endl;
        }
    }
   
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if ((int(str[i]) >= 65 && int(str[i]) <= 90) || (int(str[i]) >= 97 && str[i] <= '122'))
        {
            str[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "New string:  " << str << endl;
}
```

I cannot come up with how to implement this task with string functions (methods).

Comment: By "library string functions", do you mean "methods of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)", or [`cctype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) functions, or something else?

Comment: Yes, methods of std::string

Comment: In that case, `str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'` is [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and `(int(str[i]) >= 65 && int(str[i]) <= 90) || (int(str[i]) >= 97 && str[i] <= '122')` is a negligent version of [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) (it assumes ascii encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Some users might find it confusing when using phrasing "using library string functions".
I only assume you meant standard library functions.

There are couple of ways to achieve this:

1. [`std::replace_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)and [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)
2. [regex replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)
3. The newer [ranges replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/replace)
4. You can also use string direct `replace` function - but I don't recommend it for this kind of exercise.

Choose your favorite, I'd recommend learning all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with `without_functions()`:

- it is leaking `how_many_num`. You need to `delete[]` it when done using it. Better to use `std::vector` instead, but for such a small array, there is no point in using dynamic memory, just use a fixed array instead
- your `cout` loop is not allowing for `0` digits. You should fill the array elements with an initial value other than `0..9`, and then look for that value instead of `0`.
- your replacement loop is looking for `'122'` when it should be looking for `122` instead. However, you really should be using character literals instead of numeric ASCII codes.  It is a bad habit to use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in coding.
- your loops to count digits and replace letters can be combined into a single loop.

Now, try something more like this:

```
void without_functions(string str)
{
    int how_many_num[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        how_many_num[i] = -1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        {
            ++how_many_num[str[i] - '0'];
        }
        else if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
        {
            str[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if (how_many_num[i] != -1)
        {
            cout << "Digit " << i << " was found " << how_many_num[i] << " times" << endl;
        }
    }
   
    cout << endl << "New string:" << str << endl;
}
```

Now, to translate that into standard library functions, try something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
...

void with_functions(string str)
{
    array<int, 10> how_many_num;
    how_many_num.fill(-1);

    for (char &ch : str)
    {
        if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            ++how_many_num[ch - '0'];
        }
        else if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            ch = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if (how_many_num[i] != -1)
        {
            cout << "Digit " << i << " is found " << how_many_num[i] << " times" << endl;
        }
    }
   
    cout << endl << "New string: " << str << endl;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>
...

void with_functions(string str)
{
    map<char, int> how_many_num;

    for (char &ch : str)
    {
        if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            ++how_many_num[ch];
        }
        else if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            ch = ' ';
        }
    }

    for (const auto &elem : how_many_num)
    {
        cout << "Digit " << elem.first << " is found " << elem.second << " times" << endl;
    }
   
    cout << endl << "New string: " << str << endl;
}
```